# How to choose the right colors for print in cmyk?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, cmyk, print-production, barcodes

Hello I am creating this business card below: [image]

So the green color I used for the icons is the same as of the logo which has these values below:
[image]

My question is, are the CMYK values ok?

I will be creating the business card using CMYK and offset printing.

And my second question is about the qr barcode.

The qr barcode is PNG, and the values of it are like this:
[image]

Would these values of CMYK cause the barcode to not be readable?

Comment: ask your printer if they can do a hard-copy proof of your template before you commit to printing 1,000s of cards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need CMYK color mode? Do you say they are going to be printed in offset? This means that you need a massive amount of them, like 1000 for each name and you have like 20 different names at least.

So the first part is to define print mode. You either will print that in some artisanal way like silk print where you need spot inks, or you will use some digital format so you are probably fine with RGB and let the printer do the conversion.

If you still need CMYK, define the paper and the dominant standard in your region. US, Europe or Japan, and then define the color profiles for that combination. (Swop, Gracol, Fogra, euro, japan, iso, etc.) Ask the printer for the best one to use and ask for the Maximum TOC. People contradict themselves because sometimes ask for one profile and then ask to limit it to 300% which is another profile.

---

As you are so new to printing, ask for a calibrated proof print. No one can decide if those values are ok, especially because your overall process is a bit messy, reading your other questions. **You have NOT defined the colors using a color standard, for example, Pantone colors**.

---

**The QR**, depending on the size could have a rich black or a color combination.

**For small sizes use only one flat ink at 100%**, for example, c0m0y0k100

For big sizes, where each square has several lines of screening (LPI), let's say 4-8 you can use a screened color, for example, one of your corporation colors.

Remember that a QR minimum recommended size is around 2x2 cm, but this also depends on the density of the code. It is not the same a 32x32 to a 128x128.

A vector QR code will be sharper than a raster image.

---

As you are so new when printing, I really recommend you to ask a professional designer to supervise your work, because you potentially can lose a lot of money. A digital error is easy to fix, but a printed one is not.

Answer (score 0):

In my 20 years of experience, simplifying CMYK values to even numbers and increments of 5 work best to limit color shifting.  QR code colors just need a contrast between white and a color.  However, I think you can figure that out on your own by trying to scan it in any possible color you come up with.